# The useEffect returned function never called while App closes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am removing some values when app closes, and I am doing it with useEffect but it does not works.

```
export default RootComponent = ()=> {

useEffect(()=> {

   return ()=> {

     // on Android 10 Galaxy A60: this function never invoked, when app closes 
     // on Android 6 Galaxy note9 clone: this function invoked, when app closes

   }

}, []);

return (
 // ...
);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that is returned in `useEffect(() => {}, [])` is called when the component is dismounted. To call a function when browser tab, you can use this package. https://github.com/jacobbuck/react-beforeunload

Comment: Thank you @Prime I should switch to the class Component ?

Comment: I am not using any web app this on Android

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check again.

Comment: Please let me know shoudl I call in returned function the `setupBeforeUnloadListener();` or just inside useEffect ?

Comment: `setupBeforeUnloadListener()` should be called when component's mounted. It will setup event listener. You can use current code.

Comment: `TypeError: window.addEventListene is not a function.`

Comment: I think you make a typo issue. not `window.addEventListene`, but `window.addEventListener()`

Comment: addEventListener is same

Comment: Do you use typescript?

Comment: No I am using javascript

Comment: I've done some research and it would be great to use this package instead. I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you for your efforts, unfortunately this does not works also. I am using `react-native` not reactjs